# Error in Autoplot function for time series

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, forecasting

Autoplot function gives the following error when plotting a time series example from Forecasting: Principles and Practice - Hyndman and Athanasopoulos:

```
library(forecast)
library(fpp2)
data(ausbeer)
beer2 <- window(ausbeer, start=1992)
fit.beer <- tslm(beer2 ~ trend + season)
summary(fit.beer)
autoplot(beer2, series="Data") +
  autolayer(fitted(fit.beer), series="Fitted") +
  xlab("Year") + ylab("Megalitres") +
  ggtitle("Quarterly Beer Production")

# the error is:
# Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only
```

It appears to be from the autolayer line.

I can't figure out how to format the x-values as a date.

Comment: No error. works as desired for me.

Comment: Please include any additional packages: `data set ‘ausbeer’ not found`

Comment: don't use autoplot - but my wild guess `as.Date(your x)` ??

Comment: The ausbeer data is in the time series format, which makes it unclear to me how I reformat the x values as dates.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (I haven't tried with your code, but I faced a similar issue previously):

```
library(scales)
.....
autoplot(beer2, series="Data") + + scale_x_yearmon() + 
autolayer(fitted(fit.beer), series="Fitted") +
xlab("Year") + ylab("Megalitres") +
ggtitle("Quarterly Beer Production")
```